# How to automatically send http request directly from my computer

Tags: javascript, python, html, http

I want to automatically login to a webpage without already logged in to a session, search something through its search bars, and load the HTML of the last search result from the result list. Do anyone have any direction on how to do this?

Unlike websites like Google, the final url does not change after the search. It appears that the search bar send a form about the search request and change the inner html of the webpage, without changing the title url, which makes things more difficult

If you want to know what this is for, I am doing some web scraping.

I tried making an HTML that automatically submits a form that mimics the form of the login page and search bars:

```
<body onload="document.frm1.submit()">
  <form action="http://XXXXX.com/login" name="frm1">
    <input type="text" name="username" value="Smith" />
    <input type="password" name="password" value="12345" />
  </form>
</body>
```

It works. However, it gets very complicated when the HTML of the webpage is very complicated. Right now I am just trying to mimic it based on what I see in F12 inspect HTML. Also, this method does not allow action chains. After I logged in, I am not able to search the items. And it seems like the page does not store sessions, because when I open a new tab I have to log in again, but I am not very sure.

I am trying to view the http header directly through the browser's inspect elements >> networks function.  But I still haven't figured out exactly how to use the information there.

I also tried selenium (python), but its sendkeys function is so slow especially when I can only use Internet Explorer (a few seconds per character!). And Even if I use selenium, I am not sure why but some buttons in the webpage cannot be clicked.

For the second part (getting the html) I haven't done it as well, but I guess I will just use standard libraries like BeautifulSoup?

There are a few websites I need to work on. One of them is https://www.mdsystem.com

update:
I tried copying the form data from chrome>>insepct elemenets>>networks and sending the form using python library requests. However, it returns the following:

```
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
if (window['AdfPage'] && AdfPage.PAGE && AdfPage.PAGE.__getSessionTimeoutHelper())
        AdfPage.PAGE.__getSessionTimeoutHelper().__alertTimeout();
else {
        alert('Because of inactivity, your session has timed out and is no longer active.  Click OK to reload the page.');
        window.location.replace(window.location.href);}
</script>
</head></html>
```

Which is weird. If I submit the form manually from a browser it will show the search results.

Comment: There's no general answer to this, it depends on the specifics of the web site. It might use AJAX instead of submitting a form.

Comment: .. or the login could include hidden fields that you're missing (use Google developer tools to check).  The login could also be returning cookies that you fail to pass on in your later calls.